# Libre Office Automatic Hyperlink Creation Not Wanted

Tags: libreoffice

LO 6.4.7.2 on Ubuntu.
Libre Office automatically creates hyperlinks of text entries in Calc and Writer that take the form of an email address or other URI, apparently as a default. 
That is rarely desirable in my work and I want to spare myself the extra step of having to "Remove Hyperlink" - which process frequently gives unexpected results wasting even more time. 
I cannot find an entry to turn off the automatic creation of hyperlinks.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writer Menu: Tools > Autocorrect >

- While typing
  or
- Autocorrect options >

```
/ Options \
...
 M   T
[ ] [ ]  URL Recognition
```

M - while modifying existing text
T - while typing

Ref:
https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Writer/025